# Automate Rails form POSTs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a large number of JSON files and would like to automate POSTing them all via my form.  I tried via curl:

```
curl -d "startup[name]='test startup'" -d "startup[url]='http://startup.com'" -d "startup[category]=['','Analytics']" -d "startup[founded(1i)]='2013'" -d "startup[founded(2i)]='5'" -d "startup[founded(3i)]='1'" -d "startup[description]='blah'" http://localhost:5000/startups
```

But I get an HTML response with a trace that says `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

How can I easily automate my POSTs.  If I can do this easier in Ruby I would love to hear how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable csrf protection on controller-by-controller basis:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

Add the above line to `StartupsController`, now the form will submit

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do a get request to the new action first, say

```
http://localhost:5000/startups/new
```

Then parse html to find out the authenticity token, use this as one of the parameters of your POST request